# Выбор между .load и $.get

Tags: jquery, ajax

На странице есть меню с кнопками, при нажатии на которые должен подгружаться контент из php-файлов и вставляться в соответствующие дивы. Страница статичная, без CMS.
Подскажите какой из 2х описаных в заголовке вариантов подойдет для этого лучше всего? Какая между ними разница?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> должен подгружаться контент из php-файлов и вставляться в соответствующие дивы

Это практически описание работы функции [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Поэтому в данном случае стоит использовать ее.

[$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) делает **только** GET запрос. В то же время, [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) в зависимости от параметров может делать запрос любого типа и даже выбирать конкретный элемент из результата, который надо вставить на страницу.

Для это нужно указать в параметре `url` нужный селектор через пробел.

```
 elements.load('site/url/ #element')
```

Приведенный код вставит только содержимое элемента с id=element а не всю загруженную разметку.

Разница так же заключается в возвращаемом значении: [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) возвращает [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (реализация Promise), в то время как [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) возвращает текущую коллекцию, что позволяет продолжить с ней работать.

Answer (score 2):

Если не углубляться в подробности, то разница только в том, что `$(selector).load(url)` загружает данные по url прямо в `$(selector)`, а для `$.get({...})` надо писать обработчик.

Используйте первый вариант, если он вас удовлетворяет, но если же вам надо отловить событие загрузки - используйте `$.get()`

UPDATE: В `.load()` также есть возможность подключить callback функцию при успешном завершении загрузки: [`.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Пример:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
    alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: Да, мне нужно, чтобы после успешной подгрузки файла выполнялась соответствующая функция. Я так понимаю, у .load нет такой возможности?

Comment: @Cheg извините, ошибся, редко пользую `.load`, обновил ответ